# Pandas DataFrame from SQL query: difference in dates is wrongly displayed

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, dataframe

Given a table in Redshift (PostgreSQL) which contains one column, called `created_at`, its type is a timestamptz, looking like 2015-04-01 07:08:32.631+00, for instance.

I wrote a query to compute the difference, in days, between any two pairs of ordered rows (ordered on this field). Query is

```
SELECT created_at, 
       created_at - LAG(created_at) OVER(ORDER BY created_at ASC) AS diff, 
       EXTRACT('day' FROM created_at - LAG(created_at) OVER(ORDER BY created_at ASC)) AS day_diff
FROM
  (SELECT MAX(created_at) as created_at
   FROM table 
   GROUP BY created_at)
ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

I need to get the MAX of the field because there can be multiple rows with the same value, so it's a way to get one.

And I get, from a SQL UI, these results:

[image]

Now, when I run the same query and build a DataFrame as

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_sql_query(q, engine)
```

where `q` is the query string from above, I get that despite the day_diff is right, the diff column always displays '0 days 00:00:00', as if it were somehow converted and it's wrong. The `engine` var comes from `sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)` which I use for connecting to the database.

Comment: Did you try to extract the `diff` in seconds, like the way you did with the days?
It really looks like a datetype-conversion thingy.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis Extracting whatever part would work, as shown. But I'd like to see the full diff object and question is where does the conversion take place and how to prevent it.

Comment: When you say `the full diff object` what exactly do you mean?

What about using this query: 
`SELECT created_at, 
       EXTRACT('second' FROM created_at - LAG(created_at) OVER(ORDER BY created_at ASC)) AS diff
       EXTRACT('day' FROM created_at - LAG(created_at) OVER(ORDER BY created_at ASC)) AS day_diff
FROM
  (SELECT MAX(created_at) as created_at
   FROM table 
   GROUP BY created_at)
ORDER BY created_at ASC`
If you get the second_diff, you can display them how you want using python/pandas.

Comment: @JanZeiseweis I mean I'd like to see what I see in that image above (from a SQL UI, not Pandas), instead of seeing all 0's. With your query I do get the seconds only. Maybe you meant using a DATE_TRUNC, but I'd also like to know what is Pandas doing!

Answer (score 2):

If you can get seconds as I described in my comment, you can convert them into the desired format.

let's say you have your DataFrame df:

```
def format_seconds(seconds):
    days, reminder = divmod(seconds, 60*60*24)
    hours, reminder = divmod(reminder, 60*60)
    minutes, reminder = divmod(reminder, 60)
    return "%d days %02d:%02d:%02d" % (days, hours, minutes, reminder)

df['formated_diff'] = df['diff'].apply(format_seconds)
```